# Count the number of rows that contain certain string and aggregate

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following set of rows in my DB:

```
 USER   |  ACTIVITY
'User1' | 'User1 liked FeatureX'
'User1' | 'User1 liked FeatureY'
'User2' | 'User2 followed FeatureX'
```

I want to run a query that does the following:

```
select User, 
       count(Activity like '%liked%') as LikedActivity, 
       count(Activity like '%followed%') as FollowedActivity
from db.Table 
group by USER
```

In another word: I want to retrieve the number of "feature likes" and "feature follows" for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUM` here along with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    User, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Activity LIKE '%liked%'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LikedActivity, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Activity LIKE '%followed%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FollowedActivity
FROM db.Table 
GROUP BY User;
```

We could also use `COUNT` here, which would lead to an even tidier looking query:

```
SELECT
    User, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Activity LIKE '%liked%'    THEN 1 END) AS LikedActivity, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Activity LIKE '%followed%' THEN 1 END) AS FollowedActivity
FROM db.Table 
GROUP BY User;
```

Comment: ah i see!! works great, thank you! Is there any performance difference between the two?

Comment: @Gio I would expect very little performance difference between the two.  You can run `EXPLAIN` on both queries to see the differences.